# How to match Date and Time in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge, dataset

I need to match and merge two database sets in python. They both have a column for date and one for time, I need to match the dates first then sort by time and delete the empty spaces I think.
The two datasets

[image: dataset 1]

[image: dataset 2]

The output that I need is basically the same just matched by time and date and merged into one. Also the rows in the first that won't be matched by time can be deleted.

This is what I have so far, but it only matches the dates.

```
df = pd.concat([pr,ds])
dd = df.groupby('Date').agg(lambda x:sorted(set(x), key=list(x).index)).stack()
```

Comment: do you need all columns in the final df? 
try pd.merge( pr,ds , on = ['date','time'], how = inner)

Comment: Sweet, I didn't know I could enter multi conditions directly into this function, that did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple join.

```
pd.merge( pr,ds , on = ['date','time'], how = inner)
```